# How to make justified alignment of text written in a text view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, textview

In my app for iPad I have to use a Text View. I wrote some text in it. I wanted to make the alignment of the text justified, but their are only 3 options for text alignment, a) Left Alignment, b) Center Alignment and c) Right Alignment. Their is no option of making it justified. So how can I make the alignment of the text in the text view in Justified manner?
Regards
PC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use a UITextView, use something that can justify such as UIWebView.